# If flash drives have an address mapping lookup table for wear leveling, how does the memory for the lookup table not wear out?

Tags: flash, wear-leveling

First of all, sorry if this is in the wrong SE. Not sure where else this should go.

To my understanding, flash drives accomplish wear leveling by having a microcontroller remap sections of memory on the fly. These new locations need to be remembered, so it must use some sort of extra memory for a lookup table. My question is, how does this extra memory not fail in exactly the way the microcontroller is trying to prevent?

Or am I completely misunderstanding how flash drives work?

Answer (score 2):

Because the mapping table itself will not change that often, so it wears out less or at least not more than the data the table references to.

Comment: You can also just reserve the first so many cells for the master mapping entry. If the first cells wears out and can no longer be erased, you fill it with 0's and then use the second cell. Repeat if the second cell wears out.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That information should go into an answer, either this answer or your own. It is good information.